# Postfix: Keep mails in Backup-Queue even if next hops says 500

Tags: postfix, email-server

We have lost some mails because the next smtp hop (internal server) had a broken configuration  and replied with 500 "won't relay".

Is there a way to configure postfix to keep the mails in some backup queue and don't drop this mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `soft_bounce = yes` in `main.cf` ([reference](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#soft_bounce)).